# What function $f(x) = f(1/x)$ has limits $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0, \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, and $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, symmetry

What (simple) function has the following properties:

- It maps the positive reals (except for 1) to positive reals: $f: (0,1) \cup (1, +\infty) \to  (0, +\infty)$.
- It is symmetric about reciprocals: $f(x) = f(1/x)$.
- It has limits $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0, \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, and $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \infty$.
- It may incorporate one arbitrary constant (a parameter), which we'll call $d$, ranging from $(0, + \infty)$.  The function $f$ is linear in $d$.

Surprisingly, I'm not able to construct *any* function which has all of those properties.

Background: In the context of a particular problem, I've been able to show that the solution involves a function $f$.  I've yet to figure out what $f$ is, but I *can* show it has the properties above.  I'd like to use them to form a candidate function, which I can then perhaps use as an ansatz or refine to get the solution.

---

### Clarification

Of course, I could piecewise construct such a function, but this is unlikely to be a good ansatz.  I'm looking for a function which has these properties "naturally", for some definition of "naturally".  As an inspiration, consider the gamma function: There are many (infinite) functions that equal factorial on the integers, but only one "natural" function.

I don't know how to define "natural" - if I did, that would probably be my answer - but piecewise is certainly not.

---

## More information

For those interested, the problem I'm working on is the [Circle of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius) ([Interactive](https://www.geogebra.org/m/EdgDmrsf)), which has complex equation $$|z - z_0| = \rho |z - z_1|.$$

[image: Source: http://www.mathematicalgemstones.com/gemstones/pearl/circles-of-apollonius-and-magnetism/]

I was trying to find a function that maps the constant $\rho$ to the radius of the circle, and deduced that it must have the above properties (with $d = |z_1 - z_0|$).

Indeed, it seems the answers from "Fluffy Alpaca" and aschepler are correct, in that the radius seems to be *proportional* to $$\frac x {(x-1)^2} = \frac 1 {x + \frac 1 x - 2}$$ where $x = \rho^2$. I've yet to determine the constant of proportionality, but assume it is linear in $d$ (because the radius must be linear in some measure of distance, which can only come from $d$), suggesting $$\text{radius} = \frac d {x + \frac 1 x - 2}.$$

Comment: Well, just define something that works  on $(0,1)$ and extend it by symmetry.  $f(x)=\frac 1{1-x}-1$ for instance, but that choice isn't terribly important... all you need is the right behavior at $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @lulu: you beat me by 56 seconds!

Comment: Maybe something like ${1\over|\log(x)|}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$g(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)-2}$$

This should work - try playing around a bit with it on desmos for example.

Comment: Thanks.  To meet the positive criteria, I can use $h(x) = [f(x)]^2$.

Comment: @SRobertJames There's no need to, because for $x>0$ we have $g(x) \geq 2$ and so $f(x)>0$

Comment: Interesting: For at least one (unknown) value of $d$, the answer seems to be $[\frac {1+x}{1-x}]^2 - 1$, which, if my division is correct, equals $4 \cdot f(x)$.  Is that correct?

Comment: This indeed seems to be the function! - See updated post.

Answer (score 2):

One function satisfying these properties, and without "definition by cases", is

$$ f(x) = \frac{d}{(\ln x)^2} $$

This comes from noticing $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln x = -\infty$, $\ln 1 = 0$, and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \ln x = +\infty$, then applying the power $-2$ to get the desired limits.

Or along the same lines,

$$ f(x) = \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2} $$

(That's $d$ times $x$, not a differential form.)

Comment: Thank you.  It's worth noting that $\frac x {(x-1)^2} = \frac 1 {x + \frac 1 x - 2}$.

Comment: This indeed seems to be the function! - See updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Take any function $g:(0,1)\to(0,\infty)$ that has $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1}g(x)=\infty$. For instance, $g(x)=dx/(1-x)$ with $d\in(0,\infty)$. Then just define
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
g(x),  & \text{if $x\in(0,1)$} \\
g(1/x),  & \text{if $x\in(1,\infty)$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes, please see update that I'm trying to avoid piecewise.